# Is there a way to query ehcache map keys with wild chars?

Tags: java, spring-boot, ehcache

I'm using ehcache implementation with a spring boot cache interface. I'm loading a table as a cache.

Example lets we have a `users` table with columns

```
1. userId | 2.userName | 3.someUUID
-----------------------------------
```

Here I may need to query the table with userId or userName or someUUID
How to do this with spring cache.

Have tried 
`userName+"_"+userId+"_"+someUUID` as key and value as an Object in the Map.but want to know how to do wild char search ;)

**Cache Creation**

```
Cache cache = cacheManager.getCache("seccache");
cache.put(userName+"_"+userId+"_"+someUUID, Object)
```

**Fetching**

```
ValueWrapper cache = cacheManager.getCache("seccache").get(key);
```

Want to know how to get the wild char search.

Answer (score 1):

Ehcache 2.x has an option for doing that, see [the relevant documentation](https://www.ehcache.org/generated/2.10.4/html/ehc-all/#page/Ehcache_Documentation_Set%2Fco-srch_about_searching.html). Note however that this is not what a cache is designed for. And in particular the OSS implementation of Ehcache search is effectively a brute force search.

Ehcache 3.x does not have that feature.